# UPDATE Query without WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, database, sql-update, where-clause

Can the `UPDATE` query be used without a `WHERE` clause? And if so in what conditions?

Comment: In oracle, you can omit the `where` clause => all rows in the table are updated. I don't know for the other ORDBMS but i think that this will update all the table rows too.

Comment: Yes you can as has already been answered. That being said, I am of two minds on this. I've seen disasters happen when a `WHERE` clause is accidentally omitted and every record rather than just one is updated. While I'd love to see `UPDATE` without `WHERE` being treated as a syntax error, I'm also thinking that this is not the job of a programming language.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

if you don't use the `WHERE` clause all the records on the table will be affected

Comment: i still confuse. if we always have to state the where clause for each update on the same table, isnt this costs the server. why cant we just identify the row from last query and use it for next query?

Comment: What if that's exactly what I want to happen? Do I need to add `WHERE 1=1` ?

Comment: @ChristoKiwi PostgreSQL throws an error (`Unsafe query: 'Update' statement without 'where' updates all table rows at once`) in this case and does not make any changes. Looks like it's not allowed to do updates without a `WHERE` clause. However, your suggestion `WHERE 1=1` or any other trivially true statement (e.g. `WHERE id > 0`) seems to make the trick.

Comment: I have been using SQL in many flavors for 25 years now, it's the first time I see this warning. I think it's good to see it, but I need a better way to avoid the trick "1=1" ...

Comment: you could use primary_key = primary_key instead of where 1=1. It makes more visual sense to me that way.

Comment: `1=1` or any other "trick" has the unvaluable advantage of making the intent very explicit, so yes, PostgreSQL is being very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

So, I think when you want to update the whole field for some kind of reasons like updating the status of users enrollment to free for all users.

```
UPDATE users SET status = "free";
```

Answer (score 1):

The `UPDATE` statement in SQL is used to update records in the table. We can modify one or multiple records (rows) in a table using `UPDATE` statement. If you do not use `WHERE` clause in `UPDATE` statement, all the records in the table will be updated.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE test.test
SET name='aaaa'
WHERE true

This updates all the rows and gets rid of the error
Unsafe query: 'Update' statement without 'where' updates all table rows at once