# Mysql update error: 'Update' statement without 'where' updates all table rows at once

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to run this query:

```
UPDATE users as u
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(updated_at) as start, h.uuid
       From users_history as h
       where h.promoted = true) new on new.uuid = u.uuid
 SET u.start_time = new.start;
```

And I'll get the following error:

```
Unsafe query: 'Update' statement without 'where' updates all table rows at once
```

How should I rewrite this query to fix this problem?
I'm trying to set start_time on the user table to the first time in the user_history, the user got promoted.

Comment: How about adding WHERE true at the end of query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UPDATE Query without WHERE Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163047/update-query-without-where-clause)

Comment: Create a view instead.

Answer (score 1):

The message is informing you that your query is "unsafe" (by some standard of safety) because it does not include a `WHERE` clause.

It is issued because some [MySQL feature known as "safe updates"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_safe-updates) has been enabled on your database.

In other words, MySQL is postulating that you intended to include a `WHERE` clause, but you forgot to include it, so this query as it stands is about to destroy your database by modifying every single record, so MySQL is preventing you from doing this in an attempt to save you from yourself. (In doing so, MySQL is also postulating that you are working on the original instance of a database, that the database is very important for your operations, and that you have been taking no backups. But I digress.)

- One way to work around this problem is to disable that feature on your database.  This depends on how your database has been configured, and you might not even have the necessary privileges to do so.
- Another way to work around this is to use the following construct:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
(your query here)
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
```

- The best way to work around this is to add a `WHERE` clause that selects everything.  The way to do this varies from database system to database system; some will accept the very reasonable `WHERE TRUE` clause; others require something more complicated, like `WHERE 1=1`.  The point is, this is a `WHERE` clause that simply selects everything, just as the absence of a `WHERE` clause would select everything. By including a `WHERE` clause we are telling MySQL that we know what we are doing and it does not need to save us from ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

Add where codition as `WHERE new.uuid = u.uuid` as follows

```
UPDATE users as u
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(updated_at) as start, h.uuid
       From users_history as h
       where h.promoted = true) new on new.uuid = u.uuid
 SET u.start_time = new.start
 WHERE new.uuid = u.uuid;
```